# Am I implementing the monkey test correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, random

I have written the following code to perform a three-letter [monkey test](http://file:///Users/titus/Downloads/tuftests%20(4).pdf) on the notorious Randu number generator.

```
from itertools import product
from scipy.stats import chisquare
from numpy.random import randint


multiple = 10
number_of_random_numbers = 17576*multiple #There are 17576 possible three letter words. Therefore it's easy use a sequence length of
                                        # 17576 times some natural number.

expectation = multiple     #Given that the null hypothesis is true
                           # (equivalent to saying: given that the random sequence is iid and uniform) we expect
                           # that each word occurs once every 17576 times. Therefore the expected occurrence of each
                           # combinations is equal to the multiple. If we have a random sequence of length 2*17576 we
                           # expect each word to occur twice.

def seedlcg(init_Val):
    global rand
    rand = init_Val

def lcg_randu():
    a = 65539
    c = 0
    m = 2**31
    global rand
    rand = (a*rand + c) % m
    return rand/m

seedlcg(30000)

random_sequence = []
for i in range(1,number_of_random_numbers):
    random_sequence.append(lcg_randu())
random_sequence = [math.ceil(26*number) for number in random_sequence]
#  def collect_words():
#       This function collects the observed words from the sequence of random numbers. It
#       returns a list that contains the observed words.

def collect_words(random_sequence):
    list_of_words = []
    for i in range(0,len(random_sequence)):
        list_of_words.append((random_sequence[i-2],random_sequence[i-1], random_sequence[i]))
    return list_of_words


# def initiate_list_of_possible_words():
#       This function initiates a list of all possible words and returns that list.

def initiate_list_of_possible_words():
    alphabet = [x for x in range(1,27)]
    list_of_possible_words = [letter for letter in product(alphabet, repeat=3)]
    return list_of_possible_words

# def count_words(observed_words):
#       This function checks how many times each possible word combination occurred. It returns
#       a list with the number of occurrences for each word.

def count_words(observed_words):
    list_of_possible_words = initiate_list_of_possible_words()
    word_count = []
    for word in list_of_possible_words:
        word_count.append(observed_words.count(word))
    return word_count

word_combinations = collect_words(random_sequence) #Collect the observed words from the sequence
word_count = count_words(word_combinations) #Collect how many times each possible word has occurred.

print(chisquare(word_count, multiple)) #Compute and print the Chisquare statistic and the corresponding p-value.
```

When I run this code I get the following result:

```
Power_divergenceResult(statistic=117915.47220000002, pvalue=0.0)
```

This code is supposed to count the occurrences of every possible three letter word in the generated random sequence and then perform a chi-square test. I understand that this code can probably be made to run ten times faster. However, I don't really believe that this chi-square test statistic has a p value of zero (this would mean that the monkey test would reject the the idd-ness of the Randu generator).

**Question:** Have I made a mistake in my code? Is there something I don't comprehend that results in this extreme p-value?

Comment: Are the values in your `random_sequence` supposed to be integers in the range 1 to 26? It looks as though your random sequence consists entirely of floats in the range [0, 1) instead. (So the word counts are all zero.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks! I edited that out, somehow that line of code went missing when copy-pasting.

Comment: IOW, I think you want something like `random_sequence.append(1+int(26*lcg_randu()))` instead of `random_sequence.append(lcg_randu())`. But even with that change, a p-value of 0.0 shouldn't be surprising. The RANDU generator really _is_ that bad.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Wow ok I didn't expect that! Do you happen to know whether other tests like the runs test or the permutation test would reject the idd-ness and randomness of the Randu as well? Thanks for your suggestion, I'll implement it into my code!